# Rainbow Scattering Potential Function

Tags: classical-mechanics, scattering

I am studying the 3rd edition of Goldstein's *Classical Mechanics* and in the discussion of scattering in a central field, the author mentions (but does not give the formula for) the following potential in the context of "rainbow scattering" (p. 111):

[image]

I was wondering if this is a well-known potential and, if so, where could I look to find the defining formula?

*Edit*: In my efforts to determine the formula, I checked several classical mechanics texts (those of Greiner, of Pars, and of Hand and Finch) and used MATLAB to try to fit data extrapolated from the image to a curve to give me a clue as to the functional form. All of this was to no avail.

Comment: To me the shape looks like reversed [S-Matrix modulus](https://inis.iaea.org/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/22/018/22018262.pdf), i.e. $1-|S(l)|$.

Comment: Thanks! Based on the paper you sent, I think my potential is some version of the Woods-Saxon potential. Does this seem reasonable?

Comment: Yes, I think it's plausible.